# Mittag -Leffler function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators, fractional-calculus

I am just reading about mittag leffler function and its properties :

The hyperbolic functions of order n .which are generalizations of the hyperbolic sine and cosine can  be expressed in terms of mittag -leffler function:

$
{h}_{r}{\mathrm{(}}{z}{\mathrm{,}}{n}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\mathop{\sum}\limits_{{k}\mathrm{{=}}{0}}\limits^{\mathrm{\infty}}{\frac{{z}^{{nk}\mathrm{{+}}{r}\mathrm{{-}}{1}}}{{\mathrm{(}}{nk}\mathrm{{+}}{r}\mathrm{{-}}{1}{\mathrm{)}}}}\mathrm{{=}}{z}^{{r}\mathrm{{-}}{1}}{E}_{n\mathrm{,}r}{\mathrm{(}}{z}^{n}{\mathrm{).}}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{(}}{r}\mathrm{{=}}{1}{\mathrm{,}}{2}{\mathrm{,...}}{n}{\mathrm{)}}
$

Is there any explanation for that relationship .

Comment: $E_{2,1}(z^2)=\cosh(z)$

Comment: And if I have it for n order

Comment: What is $E_{n,r}$ ? And did you mean $(nk+r-1)!$

Comment: It's the two paramater mittag leffler function ...